# Preimage of prime Weil divisor is prime Weil divisor in Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a noetherian normal scheme, let $\mathbb{A}^1$ be the affine line over $\mathbb{Z}$, and let $X \times \mathbb{A}^1$ be the fibre product over $\mathbb{Z}$ with projection
$$  \pi: X \times \mathbb{A^1} \longrightarrow X   . $$

In Chapter II of Hartshorne, he shows that the Weil divisor class groups satisfy
$$ \text{Cl}(X \times \mathbb{A}^1) \simeq \text{Cl}(X).$$
To do this he defines a group homomorphism,
$$\Psi: \text{Cl}(X) \rightarrow \text{Cl}(X \times \mathbb{A}^1)  $$ by $\Psi(Z) = \pi^{-1}(Z)$.

My question is why $\pi^{-1}$ should even be a Weil divisor. In particular, why does it have codimension $1$ in $X \times \mathbb{A}^1$?

I think this can be done by appealing to the faithful flatness of $\pi$, but at that point in Hartshorne no such notion has been introduced or even mentioned. So I am wondering if there is some easy way to see it in this case?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is the dimension of fibers theorem, although this is probably tremendous overkill.

Comment: I may be saying something silly here but isn’t $\pi^{-1}(Z)\cong Z\times \mathbb{A}^1$?

Comment: @Samir not silly at all, since that is true. But maybe I am the silly one for not seeing why that has codimension 1.

Comment: I see. So is your confusion more about how to compute the dimension of fiber products then?